# Deleting all keys from a hash that have the same beginning

Tags: ruby, hash, key

I want to delete all keys from a hash that have the same beginning, for example

```
myhash[:x_key_a]
myhash[:x_key_b]
myhash[:x_key_c]
```

so I'd like to delete all the keys that start with `x` from `myhash`

Is there a better way to do this other than going over all keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myhash.delete_if{ |key, _| key.to_s.start_with?('x') }
```

Comment: I'd do the same. However, the answer to the OP's question is "no", you have to iterate over all keys.

Comment: by going over all the keys I meant - going over all the keys the nonmagic way with keys.each, etc..

Comment: delete_if still does the nonmagic way under the hood! I agree that it is the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

```
myhash = {}

myhash[:x_key_a] = 1
myhash[:x_key_b] = 2
myhash[:y_key_c] = 3

p myhash.delete_if{ |key, _| key.match(/^x/) }
# => {:y_key_c=>3}
```